# Report Viewer Issue(.rdlc) in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, asp.net-3.5

I am creating a new rdlc report file in VS 2010 in a web application. This project already consists some existing rdlc files which were build in VS 2008.
When I run the project and view the report I get the following error:

**An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and after checking the following link :

https://cmatskas.com/resolving-rdlc-error-the-report-definition-is-not-valid-in-visual-studio-2012/

I found out that the default referenced Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll version was for VS 2008 which is Version : 9.0.0 
so i searched for the dll and i found it in :

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

after referencing it , it worked successfully

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
open your rdlc file as xml.
replace http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/ to http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/ in both xmlns:cl and xmlns

Comment: I tried changing 2008 to 2010. But its giving compilation error:

Comment: The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Comment: It seems that you have an old version of ReportViewer.WebForms. Consider updating to ReportViewer 2010.

Comment: This is the link from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442

Comment: Note that you have to remove the old reference from you project and add the new one.

Comment: @mrida Thanks to your comment, I realized my .rdlc file is accessible with ReportViewer 11 (i.e. Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll 11.0.0.0) but not with 10.